# Why does ruby's JSON parser eat my backslash?

Tags: ruby, regex, escaping, backslash

The following example in JSON format contains one backslash, and if I run `JSON.load`, the backslash disappears:

```
JSON.load('{ "88694": { "regex": ".*?\. (CVE-2015-46055)" } }')
# => {"88694"=>{ "regex"=>".*?. (CVE-2015-46055)"}}
```

How can I keep the backslash?

My goal is to have this structure, and whenever I need, read the file, load the JSON into Hash, and search for those regular expressions.

UPDATE 1

here is an example what I want.

```
irb> "stack.overflow"[/.*?\./]
=> "stack."
```

I **can't** pass the regex from JSON to my string in order to catch that "**.**", because the "\." disappears.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the backslash with another backslash?

Comment: Yes, I did. And my goal is not just to print the regex, is actualy to use it.

Comment: I don't understand "UPDATE 1". `"stack.overflow"[/.*?\./]` does return
`"stack."`. The JSON string you load does not contain the backslash character. It contains an escaped period.

Comment: Exactly. I want to catch a period. But since the backslash disappears, the dot turns into regex expression for "any character". I need that backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = '{ "88694": { "regex": ".*?\. (CVE-2015-46055)" } }'
  #=> "{ \"88694\": { \"regex\": \".*?\\. (CVE-2015-46055)\" } }"

str.chars
  #=> ["{", " ", "\"", "8", "8", "6", "9", "4", "\"", ":", " ", "{", " ",
  #   "\"", "r", "e", "g", "e", "x", "\"", ":", " ", "\"", ".", "*", "?",
  #   "\\", ".",
  #   ~~~   ~~                                        
  #   " ", "(",..., "}", " ", "}"]
```

This shows us that `str` does indeed contain a backslash character followed by a period. The reason is that `str` is enclosed in single quotes. `\.` would only be treated as an escaped period if `str` were enclosed in double quotes:

```
 "{ '88694': { 'regex': '.*?\. (CVE-2015-46055)' } }".chars[25,3]
   #=> ["?", ".", " "]
```

The return value of `str` converts the single-quoted string to a double-quoted string:

```
"{ \"88694\": { \"regex\": \".*?\\. (CVE-2015-46055)\" } }"
```

`\\` is one backslash character followed by a period. With the double quotes the period can now be escaped, but it is not preceded by a backslash, only by a backspace character.

Now let's add another backslash and see what happens:

```
str1 = '{ "88694": { "regex": ".*?\\. (CVE-2015-46055)" } }' 
str1.chars == str.chars
  #=> true
```

The result is the same. That is because single quotes support the escape sequence `\\` (single backslash) (and only one other: `\'` [single quote]).

Now let's add a third backslash:

```
str2 = '{ "88694": { "regex": ".*?\\\. (CVE-2015-46055)" } }'   
str2.chars
  #=> ["{", " ", "\"", "8", "8", "6", "9", "4", "\"", ":", " ", "{", " ",
  #   "\"", "r", "e", "g", "e", "x", "\"", ":", " ", "\"", ".", "*", "?",
  #   "\\", "\\", ".",
  #   ~~~~  ~~~~  ~~~                                        
  #   " ", "(",..., "}", " ", "}"]
```

Surprised? `\\` produces one backslash character (escaped backslash in single quotes), `\` products a second backslash character (backslash in single quotes) and `.` is a period in single quotes.

We obtain:

```
s = {"88694"=>{"regex"=>".*?\\. (CVE-2015-46055)"}.to_json

JSON.parse(str)
  #=> {"88694"=>{"regex"=>".*?. (CVE-2015-46055)"}} 
JSON.parse(str1)
  #=> {"88694"=>{"regex"=>".*?. (CVE-2015-46055)"}} 
JSON.parse(str2)
  #=> {"88694"=>{"regex"=>".*?\\. (CVE-2015-46055)"}}
```

`str2` is what we want, as

```
JSON.parse(str2)["88694"]["regex"].chars[2,4]   
  #=> ["?", "\\", ".", " "]
```

We could alternatively work backwards:

```
js = {"88694"=>{"regex"=>".*?\\. (CVE-2015-46055)"}}.to_json
  #=> "{\"88694\":{\"regex\":\".*?\\\\. (CVE-2015-46055)\"}}" 

'{"88694":{"regex":".*?\\\. (CVE-2015-46055)"}}' == js
  #=> true
```

This string is the same as `str2` after all spaces outside of quoted substrings have been removed.

It appears that JSON treats two successive backslash characters as one backslash character. See @Jordan's comment.

Perhaps a reader can elaborate what JSON is doing here.

Comment: It's worth noting that `\.` is technically invalid in a JSON string, per [RFC 7159](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-7). A backslash may be followed by any of the characters `"\/bnfrt` or `u` followed by four hexadecimal digits (odd that `/` is in that list; I wonder why). Some JSON parsers will throw an error, but Ruby just elides the backslash, for some reason.

Comment: +1, but. To be short: I have a text and I have my regex, unfortunatly I can't apply my regex from the JSON. You see, puts show me "\.", but I can not manage pass that one backslash to this: **some_text.match(/regex/)**

Comment: @Cary, thank you for an awesome answer. The reason for JSON file is because I have over 30 conditions in code just to replace some text by mine, so I thought in moving all the conditions to the JSON file, and to be able to read the file and find the condition I need in any time, without having spaghetti code. Unfortunatly, this idea has this weakness.