# Ruby JSON Parse Stripping Escaped Back Slashes From String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have stringified JSON that is being parsed into a hash on my server.  My problem is some of the key names (which are all strings) have back slashes in them.   I have escaped them by replacing with double slashes,  how ever Ruby does not seem to handle the escaping, instead it removes all slashes completely when I need there to be one left over.

Heres a quick example of what im getting.

```
p = '{"blah": {"\\Something\\Else": "meh"}}'
JSON.parse(p)
=> {"blah"=>{"SomethingElse"=>"meh"}}
```

I need the "something else" part to be `\Something\Else` except it is stripping all slashes out.

Annoyingly, if I put 1 slash, it will remove that 1 slash.  If I put 4 slashes, it will display 2 slashes, and I put 3 slashes it will display 2 slashes. Seems inconsistent.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Use 3 backslashes `p = '{"blah": {"\\\Something\\\Else": "meh"}}'`
When you do a `JSON.parse(p)`
it will display: `=> {"blah"=>{"\\Something\\Else"=>"meh"}}`

but it's treated as 1 backslash.
this explains it better:
[Why does ruby's JSON parser eat my backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328677/why-does-rubys-json-parser-eat-my-backslash)